# iOS Google+ Signin SDK - use token in phonegap for authenticated calls?

Tags: cordova, oauth, google-plus, google-client

Got a question for all you Googlers / phonegap / Oauth gurus out there.  Can I use the Google+ SDK on iOS to choose an account and authenticate and then pass the token to a phonegap app where authenticated calls could be made with said token?

I'm looking for the best way to make authenticated calls with Google accounts and phonegap and iOS and this is one option...

Update:
I have been somewhat successful in getting the token from Google+ SDK - but only after the user signs in.  I can get it using [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.accessToken.

However if I try to silently log in (so the user does not have to login every time the app is used) using [signIn trySilentAuthentication]; .  When I try to get token from the finishedWithAuth method the token returned is nil.  Help!

Answer (score 2):

This should work so long as your PhoneGap app uses the same client ID that you register when creating your Google+ API project. However, the iOS SDK does not include native framework support. This might be a bit of an adventure for you--but we would love see how you do it once you are done.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Dang your not going to walk me through how to do it :)  I'm still deciding on using this approach or a total web approach.

Comment: I honestly can't walk you through it, as I haven't tried yet. But I know that it should be doable. Good luck!

Comment: having a bit of trouble obtaining oauth token.  I've updated my response above.  Would you have any insight into this?